# Windows / dhcp no internet

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

i installed a new windows 10 version from scratch. New pc, new Windows 10 installation. The PC cant connect to the internet citing "unidentified network". The ethernet itself works, but the internet access doesnt.

- When i plug in the LAN cable, the windows symbol turn from the red cross to something yellow indicating that it registers the ethernet cable and the ethernet cable should work.
- I tried the ethernet cable on a different pc, does work there with no problems at all.
- In the windows view where i can have a look at bytes send / received i can see that my connection both did send data and received some data, however very low amounts.
- I tried installing the latest lan drivers for my mainboard. Mainboard model is AB350M-HDV. I downloaded 3 different realtek lan drivers, tried them. Nothing works.
- Adapter is activated.
- In ipconfig/all it says that my local ip4v is randomly generated or something. AFAIK that ip is generated by ADAP and not provided by DHCP. It starts with 169, which points to being generated by Windows.
- I resetted the whole network stack as pointed out in other forum posts.
- i tried setting the network address, subnet mask and standard gateway to a specific one like 192.168.0.23 without any success.

Nothing works so far and i spent several hours on this. What can i do to finally get internet access on the new machine?

Thanks..

Comment: I see that you are trying to use 192.168.0.23 as a "standard gateway" but there isn't much standard about that.  Maybe .0.1 would work.  You are going to need to know more about your router in order to set things manually.  What address is the other PC set to?

Comment: No, i tried to set my ipv4 to 192.168.0.23 not my standard gateway. My other connected pcs are all not set to a static ip. They are set to automatic dhcp and it works. Just this win10 pc wont get an ip from the router. More info: ipconfig/all also shows me that the pc doesnt get a standard gateway. Its blank. So it has no connection to the router.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

Run ipconfig /all on another computer, that works!

Then you should be able to see the gateway ip...

(It is most likely 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1, if you haven't been messing with the 'Advanced LAN-settings in your router)

Btw, why don't you set your non-working computer to 'Automatically get an ip-address' in your network settings, then it would use DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

If your ip address starts with 169 then it is using APIPA. 
Try running these in the command prompt:

- ipconfig /flushdns
- ipconfig /release
- ipconfig /renew

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and it is only for windows 10 machines, all other get an IP address via dhcp. It seems that something is blocked by MS (discussions go to port 445, but it helped not for me). My solution is to set static IP-Adresses. Look [here](https://kb.netgear.com/27476/How-to-set-a-static-IP-address-in-Windows) how to do